# WebGL vertexAttribPointer points to the wrong VBO

Tags: webgl, shader

I am trying to create two meshes, a square and a triangle. The code is at the bottom.

I first create a shader program "program1", array buffer "vertexBuffer1" and an element array buffer "indexBuffer1" for the first mesh. The first mesh is a square.

Then I do the same thing for the second mesh. The second mesh is a triangle.

When I run the code I get the error:

> [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000002B76A973870]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0

I don't get the error if I comment out this line:

```
//gl.vertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0); // <- problem!
```

I think what is happening is that somehow the triangle's vbo ("vertexBuffer2") gets connected to the square's shader program ("program1"). This causes

```
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices1.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

to fail as it is trying to draw a square from the triangles vertex buffer.

I don't understand why

```
gl.vertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0); // <- problem!
```

causes "program1" to connect to "vertexBuffer2", if that is even the problem. How do I make theese two programs ("program1" and "program2") connect to each their buffers?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="450" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
    <script>
        // setup gl
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
        gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
        gl.clearDepth(1.0);

        gl.viewport(0.0, 0.0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // setup mesh 1
        // // vertex shader
        var vertexShader1 = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        var vertexShaderCode = `
            // in
            attribute vec3 position;

            void main(void) {
                gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.);
            }
        `;
        gl.shaderSource(vertexShader1, vertexShaderCode);
        gl.compileShader(vertexShader1);
        // // fragment shader
        var fragmentShader1 = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        var fragmentShaderCode = `
            precision mediump float;
            // in
            void main(void) {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1., 0., 0., 1.);
            }
        `;
        gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader1, fragmentShaderCode);
        gl.compileShader(fragmentShader1);
        // // program1
        var program1 = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(program1, vertexShader1);
        gl.attachShader(program1, fragmentShader1);
        gl.linkProgram(program1);
        gl.useProgram(program1);

        // // create buffer 1
        var vertices1 = [ // suqare
            -0.5, -0.5, 0,
            0.5, -0.5, 0,
            0.5, 0.5, 0,
            -0.5, 0.5, 0,
        ];
        var vertexBuffer1 = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer1);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices1), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        var loc = gl.getAttribLocation(program1, "position");
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(loc);

        var indices1 = [
            0,1,2,
            0,2,3,
        ];
        var indexBuffer1 = gl.createBuffer ();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer1);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices1), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        // setup mesh 2
        // // vertex shader
        var vertexShader2 = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

        gl.shaderSource(vertexShader2, vertexShaderCode); // uses same vertexShaderCode as above
        gl.compileShader(vertexShader2);
        // // fragment shader
        var fragmentShader2 = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader2, fragmentShaderCode);
        gl.compileShader(fragmentShader2);
        // // program2
        var program2 = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(program2, vertexShader2);
        gl.attachShader(program2, fragmentShader2);
        gl.linkProgram(program2);
        gl.useProgram(program2);

        // // create buffer 2
        var vertices2 = [ // triangle one less vertex than in buffer 1
            -0.5, -0.5, 0,
            0.5, -0.5, 0,
            0.5, 0.5, 0,
        ];
        var vertexBuffer2 = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer2);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices2), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        var loc = gl.getAttribLocation(program2, "position");
        // On the line below it seems like program1 instead of program2 gets connected to the vertexBuffer2
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0); // <- problem!
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(loc);

        var indices2 = [
            0,1,2,
        ];
        var indexBuffer2 = gl.createBuffer ();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer2);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices2), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        // render
        // // clear
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // // render mesh 1 (the square)
        gl.useProgram(program1);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer1);
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices1.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0); // <- this line fail
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, [gl.vertexAttribPointer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0.0/#5.13.10) specifies the state for a generic vertex attribute array.

First you create and bind `vertexBuffer1`, `indexBuffer1` and `program1`. And you specify:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer1);
....
var loc = gl.getAttribLocation(program1, "position"); // loc == 0
gl.vertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(loc);
```

Second you create and bind `vertexBuffer2`, `indexBuffer2` and `program2`. And you specify:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer2);
....
var loc = gl.getAttribLocation(program2, "position"); // loc == 0
gl.vertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(loc);
```

Finally you call:

```
gl.useProgram(program1);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer1);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices1.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

At this moment the vertex buffer state still refers to `vertexBuffer2`, because this is the last state which you specified for the generic vertex attribute with index 0.

Change yor code like this:

```
gl.linkProgram(program1);
var loc1 = gl.getAttribLocation(program1, "position");

....

gl.useProgram(program1);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer1);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(loc);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer1);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices1.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Note, it is sufficient to set the vertex attribute sate immediately before you draw a mesh. For managing different states of vertex attributes you may use [VertexArrayObjects](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#3.6), which are supported in WebGL 2.0 or available via [extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_vertex_array_object/) in WebGL 1.0.

See the code snippet:

```js
// setup gl
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
        gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
        gl.clearDepth(1.0);

        gl.viewport(0.0, 0.0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // setup mesh 1
        // // vertex shader
        var vertexShader1 = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        var vertexShaderCode = `
            // in
            attribute vec3 position;

            void main(void) {
                gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.);
            }
        `;
        gl.shaderSource(vertexShader1, vertexShaderCode);
        gl.compileShader(vertexShader1);
        // // fragment shader
        var fragmentShader1 = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        var fragmentShaderCode = `
            precision mediump float;
            // in
            void main(void) {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1., 0., 0., 1.);
            }
        `;
        gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader1, fragmentShaderCode);
        gl.compileShader(fragmentShader1);
        // // program1
        var program1 = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(program1, vertexShader1);
        gl.attachShader(program1, fragmentShader1);
        gl.linkProgram(program1);
        var loc1 = gl.getAttribLocation(program1, "position");
        
        // // create buffer 1
        var vertices1 = [ // suqare
            -0.5, -0.5, 0,
            0.5, -0.5, 0,
            0.5, 0.5, 0,
            -0.5, 0.5, 0,
        ];
        var vertexBuffer1 = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer1);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices1), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                    
        var indices1 = [
            0,1,2,
            0,2,3,
        ];
        var indexBuffer1 = gl.createBuffer ();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer1);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices1), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        // setup mesh 2
        // // vertex shader
        var vertexShader2 = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

        gl.shaderSource(vertexShader2, vertexShaderCode); // uses same vertexShaderCode as above
        gl.compileShader(vertexShader2);
        // // fragment shader
        var fragmentShader2 = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader2, fragmentShaderCode);
        gl.compileShader(fragmentShader2);
        // // program2
        var program2 = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(program2, vertexShader2);
        gl.attachShader(program2, fragmentShader2);
        gl.linkProgram(program2);
        var loc2 = gl.getAttribLocation(program2, "position");
        
        // // create buffer 2
        var vertices2 = [ // triangle one less vertex than in buffer 1
            -0.5, -0.5, 0,
            0.5, -0.5, 0,
            0.5, 0.5, 0,
        ];
        var vertexBuffer2 = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer2);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices2), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        var indices2 = [
            0,1,2,
        ];
        var indexBuffer2 = gl.createBuffer ();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer2);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices2), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        // render
        // // clear
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // // render mesh 1 (the square)
        gl.useProgram(program1);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer1);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(loc1, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0); // <- problem!
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(loc1);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer1);
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices1.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0); // <- this line fail
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="450" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```